# Check if there are existing records in the iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I want to add default entries at the first start if the app was never installed or the app is deleted from the iCloud.
The problem is: at the moment it merges with duplicates because on the first start of the app it adds new default entries.

Is there a way to detect if there are entries in the iCloud acc from the user?

Comment: just do a retrieve with the search predicate set to true. This will return all existing records if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

```
func doesRecordExist(inRecordType: String, withField: String, equalTo: String, _ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    print(withField,equalTo)
    var result = false

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(withField) == %@", equalTo)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: inRecordType, predicate: predicate)
    publicDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil, completionHandler: {results, er in

        if results != nil {
            print(results!.count)
            if results?.count == 1 {
                print(results!.count)
                result = true
            }
        }
    })
    completion(result)
}
```